# HighMaps Only Displaying Color For Last Series In US Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rce0469b/

The only color that's showing up on the highmap is the last color of the series. The data labels show up and when you hover over ONLY the data labels, the hover data appears but it doesn't for the whole state. Also the colors aren't showing up.

I noticed this happens for all data except the last in the series. When you click on the legend points, you can hide it and the colors appear.

What am I missing?

I've tried to add a lot of things in the configuration but nothing seems to work. I've even played around with trying to reorder the data but I'm outputting this data using twig so it's difficult to manipulate all that much.

```
Highcharts.mapChart("map_11045", {
    chart: {
        map: "countries/us/custom/us-all-territories",
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: ""
    },
    colors: ["#AAD7E2", "#79A8A2", "#C9AFDB", "#A0D8A0", "#E8A6B1", "#F4E992", "#E8B091", "#94B3E0", "#C0C4C3", "#CCB2A8"],
    exporting: {
        sourceWidth: 600,
        sourceHeight: 500
    },
    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {}
                }
            }
        },
        map: {
            allAreas: true,
            colorAxis: true,
            joinBy: ["hc-key", "code"],
        }
    },
    series: [{
        legendIndex: 1,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "Using QUICK Financial and Case Activities Modules",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "us-al",
            acronym: "AL",
            state_name: "Alabama",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ar",
            acronym: "AR",
            state_name: "Arkansas",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ca",
            acronym: "CA",
            state_name: "California",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-co",
            acronym: "CO",
            state_name: "Colorado",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-de",
            acronym: "DE",
            state_name: "Delaware",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-fl",
            acronym: "FL",
            state_name: "Florida",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-id",
            acronym: "ID",
            state_name: "Idaho",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-il",
            acronym: "IL",
            state_name: "Illinois",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-in",
            acronym: "IN",
            state_name: "Indiana",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ia",
            acronym: "IA",
            state_name: "Iowa",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ks",
            acronym: "KS",
            state_name: "Kansas",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ky",
            acronym: "KY",
            state_name: "Kentucky",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-la",
            acronym: "LA",
            state_name: "Louisiana",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-me",
            acronym: "ME",
            state_name: "Maine",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-md",
            acronym: "MD",
            state_name: "Maryland",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ma",
            acronym: "MA",
            state_name: "Massachusetts",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-mi",
            acronym: "MI",
            state_name: "Michigan",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-mn",
            acronym: "MN",
            state_name: "Minnesota",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-mo",
            acronym: "MO",
            state_name: "Missouri",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ne",
            acronym: "NE",
            state_name: "Nebraska",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-nv",
            acronym: "NV",
            state_name: "Nevada",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-nh",
            acronym: "NH",
            state_name: "New Hampshire",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-nj",
            acronym: "NJ",
            state_name: "New Jersey",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-nm",
            acronym: "NM",
            state_name: "New Mexico",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-oh",
            acronym: "OH",
            state_name: "Ohio",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ok",
            acronym: "OK",
            state_name: "Oklahoma",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-or",
            acronym: "OR",
            state_name: "Oregon",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-sd",
            acronym: "SD",
            state_name: "South Dakota",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-tn",
            acronym: "TN",
            state_name: "Tennessee",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ut",
            acronym: "UT",
            state_name: "Utah",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-va",
            acronym: "VA",
            state_name: "Virginia",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "pr-3614",
            acronym: "PR",
            state_name: "Puerto Rico",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "gu-3605",
            acronym: "GU",
            state_name: "Guam",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020and\u0020Case\u0020Activities\u0020Modules\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, ]
    }, {
        legendIndex: 2,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "Using QUICK Financial Module",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "us-az",
            acronym: "AZ",
            state_name: "Arizona",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ct",
            acronym: "CT",
            state_name: "Connecticut",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-dc",
            acronym: "DC",
            state_name: "District Of Columbia",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ga",
            acronym: "GA",
            state_name: "Georgia",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ms",
            acronym: "MS",
            state_name: "Mississippi",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ny",
            acronym: "NY",
            state_name: "New York",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-nc",
            acronym: "NC",
            state_name: "North Carolina",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-nd",
            acronym: "ND",
            state_name: "North Dakota",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-pa",
            acronym: "PA",
            state_name: "Pennsylvania",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-vt",
            acronym: "VT",
            state_name: "Vermont",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-wa",
            acronym: "WA",
            state_name: "Washington",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-wv",
            acronym: "WV",
            state_name: "West Virginia",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-wi",
            acronym: "WI",
            state_name: "Wisconsin",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003EUsing\u0020QUICK\u0020Financial\u0020Module\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, ]
    }, {
        legendIndex: 3,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "Developing QUICK Financial Module and Case Activities Modules",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "none"
        }]
    }, {
        legendIndex: 4,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "Developing QUICK Financial Module (none)",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "none"
        }]
    }, {
        legendIndex: 5,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "Developing QUICK and viewing other states’ data",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "none"
        }]
    }, {
        legendIndex: 6,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "Not Using QUICK",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "us-ak",
            acronym: "AK",
            state_name: "Alaska",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-hi",
            acronym: "HI",
            state_name: "Hawaii",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-mt",
            acronym: "MT",
            state_name: "Montana",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-ri",
            acronym: "RI",
            state_name: "Rhode Island",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-sc",
            acronym: "SC",
            state_name: "South Carolina",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-wy",
            acronym: "WY",
            state_name: "Wyoming",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "vi-6399",
            acronym: "VI",
            state_name: "Virgin Islands",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENot\u0020Using\u0020QUICK\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, ]
    }, {
        legendIndex: 7,
        visible: true,
        type: "map",
        name: "No Child Support Program",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: "#000000",
            format: "{point.acronym}"
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: "{point.state_name} - {point.hover_data}",
            useHTML: true
        },
        data: [{
            code: "us-tx",
            acronym: "TX",
            state_name: "Texas",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "as-6514",
            acronym: "AS",
            state_name: "American Samoa",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "as-6515",
            acronym: "AS",
            state_name: "American Samoa",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "mp-sa",
            acronym: "MP",
            state_name: "Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-fm",
            acronym: "FM",
            state_name: "Federated States of Micronesia",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-mh",
            acronym: "MH",
            state_name: "Republic of the Marshall Islands",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, {
            code: "us-pw",
            acronym: "PW",
            state_name: "Republic of Palau",
            hover_data: "\u003Cp\u003ENo\u0020Child\u0020Support\u0020Program\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n",
            link_url: ""
        }, ]
    }, {
        name: "Separators",
        type: "mapline",
        data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps["countries/us/custom/us-all-territories"], "mapline"),
        color: "#111111",
        showInLegend: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }]
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307456/highmaps-mulitple-series-cant-seen-without-disable-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`plotOptions.map.allAreas`](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.map.allAreas) set to `true`, which means all areas are rendered for every series. So only the last series, which is on top, is showing. The colors for the others are hidden beneath.

Three possible solutions:

1. Set `allAreas: false`. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/sfLw18bt/).
2. Set [`nullColor`](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.map.nullColor), potentially with or without `nullInteraction`. You could do `nullColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'`. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/sfLw18bt/1/).
3. Have a single background series which has `allAreas: true`, while the others on top have `allAreas: false`. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/sfLw18bt/2/), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309527/2732991) for details.

Comment: Dude, you're awesome! Thank you! Setting allAreas to false fixed it! I had set that based off of other things... I tried a lot to get this to work but that did the trick!